# Does Adobe's Creative Cloud let me keep full local copies of all my files?

Tags: adobe

I'm interested in subscribing to [Adobe's photography plan](https://www.adobe.com/ca/creativecloud/photography.html?promoid=NQCJRBTZ&mv=other), using Lightroom, but I'm confused & concerned with what I'm reading about the sync capability.

At Adobe's [Browse, sync, and manage assets help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/sync-files.html), it talks about syncing files *from* the computer *to* the cloud, but never says anything about *from* the cloud *to* the computer. I have no interest in keeping my files *only* in the cloud. I want to have a full copy local. And I have multiple computers. I'd like to keep all the files local to each of them. Like Dropbox.

Is it possible to always keep a full local copy of my files in Adobe's Cloud?

Comment: Lightroom does use some special file-types, like for RAW files. You may want to save a copy of your RAW files also, Lightroom likes to 'swallow' them so you can't open them anymore if you ever cancel the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you always have full local copies of all of your originals. CC *can* sync to their cloud, and keep other clients (mobile, other PCs, etc.) in sync, but you are in complete control of that. You do not have to sync to their cloud at all if you don't wish to.